# Can can with devise, admin and user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancan

I use cancan and devise, I can update delete and show but I can't create profile.
why I can't create new profile ("ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError")

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user.is_a?(Admin)
      can :manage, :all
    elsif user.is_a?(User)

        can :read, Profile do |profile|
        profile.try(:user) == user
        end
        can :update, Profile do |profile|
        profile.try(:user) == user
        end
        can :destroy, Profile do |profile|
        profile.try(:user) == user
        end
        can :create, Profile do |profile|
        profile.try(:user) == user 
    else
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Show please controller code. `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` it is strong parametrs issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have `load_and_authorize_resource` in your controller code, you need to take another step in sanitizing your inputs via a `create_params` method call in your controller.

[Here's a link to a useful resource](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Strong-Parameters)

Firstly: your CanCan user ability can be re-written as follows:

`can :create, :read, :update, :destroy, Profile, user_id: user.id`

Secondly: your admin abilities should be written after your normal user abilities, thus overriding them more successfully:

```
def initialize(user)
  # I prefer to alias CRUD actions to keep my ability files more succint
  alias_action :create, :read, :update, :destroy, to: :crud

  cannot :manage, :all #Failsafe

  can :crud, Profile, user_id: user.id
  ... #additional abilities for user

  if user.admin?
    can :manage, :all #Override previous failsafe
```

Lastly: if your Profile class `belongs_to` a User, you ought to rewrite it as such. Thus, your `profile_params` would contain a `user_id` field.

If you were to follow that (correct) paradigm, your ProfilesController's #create action would look something like:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def create
    @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)
      if @profile.save
        ...
      else
        ...
      end
  end

  private
    def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit(:user_id, ...)
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you help me out lil more I'm new to cancan. As you see I have profile nested under user, and admin should control all. Do I need to write before_action in profile controller

Comment: I updated and still when I press create i got message "ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in ProfilesController#create"

Maybe is problem because I have 2 devise models.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  load_and_authorize_resource


  # GET /profiles
  # GET /profiles.json
  def index
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @profiles = user.profiles

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.xml {render :xml => @profiles}
    end
  end

  # GET /profiles/1
  # GET /profiles/1.json
  def show
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @profiles = user.profiles.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.xml {render :xml => @profile}
      end
  end

  # GET /profiles/new
  def new
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @profile = user.profiles.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.xml {render :xml => @profile}
      end
  end

  # GET /profiles/1/edit
  def edit
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @profiles = user.profiles.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /profiles
  # POST /profiles.json
  def create
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @profile = user.profiles.create(profile_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.save
        format.html { redirect_to user_profiles_url, notice: 'Profile was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @profile }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /profiles/1
  # PATCH/PUT /profiles/1.json
  def update
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @profiles = user.profiles.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.update(profile_params)
        format.html { redirect_to user_profile_url, notice: 'Profile was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /profiles/1
  # DELETE /profiles/1.json
  def destroy
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @profiles = user.profiles.find(params[:id])

    @profile.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to job_hunters_path }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_profile
      @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit(:full_name, :phone_number, :email, :position, :years_of_experiance, :cover_letter, :resume, :reference)
    end
end
```